# Find matching list item where another list has the match strings

Tags: perl

I have a list of text strings and a hash of RE / match strings + tags and I need, unsurprisingly, to match them up. I also need to know if there is any item in the first list that isn't matched by one of the items in the second, for example:

```perl
@strings = qw(red orange yellow blue);
%matches = (
    re => "apple",
    or => "orange",
    ye => "banana",
);
```

I need to match up each of the `$strings` with a `$hash_value` (red <-> apple for example) and raise an error for 'blue'.

I can do this with two nested loops, iterating through `@strings` with the `$hash_keys` looking for a match and getting the hash value. I think I need to use a flag variable to identify whether the inner `$hash_keys` loop finished without matching anything.

I can probably also do it by iterating through the `$hash_keys` and 'grep'ing `@strings`, but I don't know how to spot unmatched $strings.

Both of those options seems really clunky and I feel like there must be a 'cleaner' way. Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT

Apologies, the code I have is something like:

```perl
foreach $string (@strings) {
  $match = "false";
  foreach $key (keys %matches) {
    if ( /$key/ =~ $string) {
      &do_my_thing($string,$matches{$key});
      $match = "true";
      break;
      }
    }
  ( $match eq "false" ) && raise_unmatched_error($string);
  }
```

This does what I want, identifies which mask (key) matched the string and also flags unmatched strings, but it just looks inelegant. It seems to me that it should be possible to use map, maybe with grep, to a) match the hash keys with the strings, and b) identify unmatched strings.

I might be over thinking it though; it works, it's probably maintainable, maybe it doesn't need to be anything else.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: What is this `$hash_keys` variable that you are talking about? It's not in your code.

Comment: Apologies, I've added my current code to the question.

Comment: You have your match operator the wrong way round - it should be `$string =~ /$key/`. Also, for a Boolean flag like `$match` it's usually better to use 0 and 1 instead of strings.

Comment: I've changed $match to 0/1, interested what effect the order of the elements with the match operator has though? I'm not that familiar with perl, mostly just do shell scripts.

Comment: @Steve: The binding operator (`=~` - which is what you use to match a string against a regex) is not commutative. Its operands need to be the right way round. The left operand is a string and the right operand is a regex match. If you swap them round (as you've done here) then Perl will interpret your regex match as a string and your string as a regex match. That's not guaranteed to work. It might work occasionally, but that would be purely accidental.

Comment: @Steve: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators for more details. People sometimes describe regex matching as looking for a needle in a haystack. The left-hand operand is the haystack; the right-hand operand is the needle.

Answer (score 3):

Take all of the keys in your hash and turn them into a regex (using the alternation operator so that you can match on any of them). You can then do one regex match against each string in `@strings`. If you put capturing parentheses around the regex, the string that matches will end up in `$1`. And if the string doesn't match the regex (as with "blue") you can display the required warning.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @strings = qw[red orange yellow blue];
my %matches = (
  re => 'apple',
  or => 'orange',
  ye => 'banana',
);

my $match_re = join '|', keys %matches;
say "DEBUG: $match_re";

for (@strings) {
  if (/($match_re)/) {
    say "$_ -> $matches{$1}";
  } else {
    say "No match for '$_'";
  }
}
```